# Authors' names in a header and footer

Tags: fancyhdr, authblk

I am using the `authblk` package together with the `fancyhdr` package in an article class document.
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\rhead{Authors}
\chead{}
\lhead{Journal name}
\cfoot{} 

\fancypagestyle{firststyle} 
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[R]{-4cm} 
    \fancyfoot[L]{{\footnotesize \textit{Journal name}}  \linebreak {\footnotesize \copyright Authors}}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 mm} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm} 
}

\begin{document}

\author[i]{И.\,О.~Фамилия1}
\author[i]{И.\,О.~Фамилия2}
\author[ii]{И.\,О.~Фамилия3}
\author[ii]{И.\,О.~Фамилия4}
\affil[i]{affil1 }
\affil[ii]{affil2 }

\title{Название}
\date{}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

What I want is to put the names of all authors (doesn’t matter how many authors an article has) in the right heading (except for the first page) and in the left footer of the first pace. Of course, I want LaTeX to do it automatically using names from the arguments of the `\author` commands. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`authblk` stores the names in a `\AB@authors` macro, however, together with the affiliation information, which is not really necessary, in my point of view for the header information.

So, `\AB@authors` can't be used directly. It's easier to hook into `\author` and grab the author names to be stored in an `expl3` `\clist` and display this list where needed.

However, the list can be very long and must be wrapped around,therefore I applied a tabular approach with a `p` - column.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}               
\usepackage{mathtext}           
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}       
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} 
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage[blocks]{authblk}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{45pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt} 
\lfoot{}
\rfoot{}
\rhead{\ABAuthorNames}
\chead{}
\lhead{\JournalName}
\cfoot{} 

\fancypagestyle{firststyle} 
{
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfootoffset[R]{-4cm} 
    \fancyfoot[L]{{\footnotesize \textit{Journal name}}  \linebreak {\footnotesize \copyright \ABAuthorNames}}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0 mm} 
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 mm} 
}


\makeatletter

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l_david_author_list
\newcommand{\storeauthorname}[1]{%
  \clist_put_right:Nn \l_david_author_list {#1}
}
\newcommand{\showauthorlist}{%
   \clist_use:Nnnn \l_david_author_list {,\space} {,\space} {\space and\space}%
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\LetLtxMacro\AB@@author\author%
\def\AB@authornames{}
\renewcommand{\author}[2][]{%
  \AB@@author[#1]{#2}% use the old definition of \author
  \storeauthorname{#2}%  store the name
}

\newcommand{\JournalName}[1][6cm]{\begin{tabular}[t]{p{#1}}Brontosaurs\end{tabular}}
\newcommand{\ABAuthorNames}[1][6cm]{\begin{tabular}[b]{p{#1}}\showauthorlist\end{tabular}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\author[i]{И.\,О.~Фамилия}
\author[i]{И.\,О.~Фамилия}
\author[ii]{И.\,О.~Фамилия}
\author[ii]{И.\,О.~Фамилия}
\affil[i]{affil1 }
\affil[ii]{affil2 }

\title{Название}
\date{}



\maketitle
\thispagestyle{firststyle}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked. There is one thing, however, I'd like to change. I really don't like the way the header looks like. It seems appropriate to make an alteration as follows: if the the number of authors is more than 2, the right header should contain either `Author 1 et al.` for articles in English or `Author 1 и др.` for articles in Russian (something like `maxcitenames=2` setting in biblatex). Also the left footer behaves kind of weird: the spaces between initials and last names in the first line are bigger than the spaces in the second line.

Comment: @David: That wasn't in your question -- I provided what you desired in the question, adding further requests is really cumbersome, because all the previous efforts was effectively useless

Comment: Yes I know. However, I find it necessary to make this alteration. So should I edit the question or ask the new one?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't think this through. If there is no easy way to make this alteration within your solution, I withdraw my comment. However, the different spaces size in the footer still doesn't seem right. Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: @David: I'll take a look later on